# Creating a new Java List of Object with fewer filed from Li

Tags: java

Let Us say that I have Object Book

```
class Book
{
   String name;
   String bookId;
   String author;
}
```

My getBooks will return a List of Books (from a different layer) but with Objects with fields like name,_id,_date,Auth,etc

I need to create a new List with books but with only few field and also mapped as different filed names .Need only name,_id and auth as name,bookId,author.
I understand we can achieve it through iterations,but what is the best way to do it with minimal steps.Using java 1.8

Comment: A word of advice, since this looks like homework, you should make a true and honest attempt and post what you have done so far. It will get your far more help than otherwise, and the help you get will be more meaningful and you'll learn more! Computer Science is hard, and if you don't learn properly it will only get harder!

Answer (score 1):

You can Use [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) to achieve this. You can define the fields need to be mapped from one to another and also can define how should it mapped using Dozer.

or if you want so solve using streams

```
    CollectionType mappedCollection = yourCollectionToMap.stream().map(b -> {
    MappingBookClass newBook = new MappingBookClass ();
    //set values needed
    newBook .setName(b.getName());
    ...
    ...
return newBook;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I tried with the following snippet as mentioned :                 
              List<NewBook> mappedCollection = list.stream().map(b -> {
   NewBook newCar = new NewBook ();
   newCar.setNewBookID(b.bookId);
   newCar.setNewBookName(b.name);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    as per the message above,but hitting the compilation error the map method is not applicable to the arguments.Am I missing anything here.

Comment: You should have to return the result from the Lambda expression inside map function. Eg : return newCar ;

Comment: Please Do accept the answer if it solves your purpose.